# How to correctly identify a series of adjacency matrices in a text?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, graphs-and-networks, import, string-manipulation

I would like to read the strongly regular graphs on at most 64 vertices from [http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~es/srgraphs.php](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/%7Ees/srgraphs.php)

```
adjMatrix = 
 Import["http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~es/SRGs/5-2-0-1", "Table"]
```

```
dim=5, degree=2, lambda=0, mu=1

01100
10010
10001
01001
00110


TOTAL NUMBER OF STRONGLY REGULAR GRAPHS = 1

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

It gives me:

```
{{"dim=5,", "degree=2,", "lambda=0,", 
  "mu=1"}, {}, {1100}, {10010}, {10001}, {1001}, {110}, {}, {}, \
{"TOTAL", "NUMBER", "OF", "STRONGLY", "REGULAR", "GRAPHS", "=", 
  1}, {}, {"%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\
%%%%%%%%%%%%"}}
```

Why did the exported result lose some zeros?

And how do we import files containing multiple matrices, such as "[26-10-3-4](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/%7Ees/SRGs/26-10-3-4)"? (`adjMatrix = Import["http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~es/SRGs/26-10-3-4"]`)

I want to convert these matrices into adjacency matrices that Mathematica can recognize, and then convert them into corresponding graphs.

```
adjMatrix = Import["http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~es/SRGs/26-10-3-4"]
```

```
{{"dim=26", "degree=10", "lambda=3", 
  "mu=4"}, {}, {1111111111000000000000000}, \
{10111000000111111000000000}, {11010100000100000111110000}, \
{11100010000010000100001111}, {11000001100001100011001100}, \
{10100001100001010000110011}, {10010000011000110010101010}, \
{10001100010010001010010110}, {10001100001000011101001001}, \
{10000011001110100001010001}, {10000010110101001100100100}, \
{1100000011001001010011001}, {1010001010000011001100101}, \
{1001100001100100000100111}, {1001010010001010101010010}, \
{1000110100010101000111000}, {1000001101110010110000010}, \
{110000101000101001010110}, {101011000100001001101010}, \
{101000110010100110100001}, {100110001011010011000100}, \
{100101010100110100001100}, {11010100100010010010101}, \
{11001001011000100111000}, {10111000001101110000001}, \
{10100110111000001001010}, {}, {1111111111000000000000000}, \
{10111000000111111000000000}, {11010100000100000111110000}, \
{11100010000010000100001111}, {11000001100001100011001100}, \
{10100001100001010000110011}, {10010000011000110010101010}, \
{10001100010010001010010110}, {10001100001000011101001001}, \
{10000011001110100001010001}, {10000010110101001100100100}, \
{1100000011001001001011010}, {1010001010000011001100101}, \
{1001100001100100000100111}, {1001010010001010110010001}, \
{1000110100010101000111000}, {1000001101110010110000010}, \
{110000101000101010010101}, {101011000000101101100010}, \
{101000110110000010101001}, {100110001011010011000100}, \
{100101010100110100001100}, {11010100100010001010110}, \
{11001001011000100111000}, {10111000101001010001001}, \
{10100110011100101000010}, {}, {1111111111000000000000000}, \
{10111000000111111000000000}, {11010100000100000111110000}, \
{11100010000010000100001111}, {11000001100001100011001100}, \
{10100001100000011000111010}, {10010000011001010010101001}, \
{10001100010011000001010011}, {10001100001000101100100101}, \
{10000011001100110101000010}, {10000010110110001010010100}, \
{1100000011001100000110110}, {1010001001000011001010101}, \
{1001011000100001010100011}, {1001000110100010100011001}, \
{1000110010010101001101000}, {1000100101011010110000010}, \
{110000110000101011000011}, {101010001001001101011000}, \
{101001010010010110100100}, {100110100101010001000101}, \
{100101001110100010001001}, {11110000000110010010110}, \
{11000101110000001101010}, {10101010101001100001100}, \
{10011100011100100110000}, {}, {1111111111000000000000000}, \
{10111000000111111000000000}, {11010100000100000111110000}, \
{11100010000010000100001111}, {11000001100001100011001100}, \
{10100001010001010010100011}, {10010001001000101000111010}, \
{10001110000000011001010101}, {10001000011110000001100110}, \
{10000100101100110100001001}, {10000010110011001110010000}, \
{1100000110000101000110101}, {1010000101001010001010011}, \
{1001100001010001010101001}, {1001010010100010010011010}, \
{1000101010010101101000010}, {1000011001101010100100100}, \
{110000011000011011001100}, {101100001001100100010110}, \
{101001100010010100111000}, {100110100101001001001010}, \
{100011001110100011000001}, {11010010001100101100001}, \
{11001100100001110000011}, {10110100010110010100100}, \
{10101010111000000011100}, {}, {1111111111000000000000000}, \
{10111000000111111000000000}, {11010100000100000111110000}, \
{11100010000010000100001111}, {11000001100001100011001100}, \
{10100001010001010010100011}, {10010001001000011001011010}, \
{10001110000000101000110101}, {10001000011100100101000011}, \
{10000100101110010000101100}, {10000010110011001110010000}, \
{1100000110000011001010101}, {1010000011000101010100110}, \
{1001100001000011110001001}, {1001001100010010100110010}, \
{1000110010101100000011010}, {1000011001111000001100001}, \
{110000101001100000111001}, {101100001011000001010110}, \
{101010100100001010101010}, {100101010010101101001000}, \
{100011001100110110000100}, {11010010001010101100100}, \
{11001010110000010011001}, {10110100010110011000001}, \
{10101100101001100000110}, {}, {1111111111000000000000000}, \
{10111000000111111000000000}, {11010100000100000111110000}, \
{11100010000010000100001111}, {11000001100001100011001100}, \
{10100001010001010010100011}, {10010000110000101000111010}, \
{10001100001010100000110101}, {10001010001001010101010010}, \
{10000110001100011010001100}, {10000001110110001101000001}, \
{1100000011000110001011001}, {1010001001000011001100110}, \
{1001100100000011100101001}, {1001011000100001010010011}, \
{1000100110111000000010110}, {1000010011011100110100000}, \
{110000101001001010010101}, {101100010000101101000110}, \
{101000101110000010101010}, {100111000011001001011000}, \
{100011100100110100100100}, {11010010101000001100101}, \
{11001010010010110011000}, {10110100010110011000001}, \
{10101001101100100001010}, {}, {1111111111000000000000000}, \
{10111000000111111000000000}, {11010100000100000111110000}, \
{11100010000010000100001111}, {11000001100001100011001100}, \
{10100001010001010010100011}, {10010000101000011010011010}, \
{10001100010000101100010110}, {10001010001101000000110101}, \
{10000101001110001001001001}, {10000010110010110101100000}, \
{1100000110000101000111001}, {1010000011001001001100110}, \
{1001100100010010001010011}, {1001001001100010100101010}, \
{1000110001001101110000001}, {1000011010110010010010100}, \
{110001001000110001010101}, {101110000000011001101100}, \
{101000011011000110011000}, {100100101110100010000110}, \
{100011100101001101000010}, {11010010100100011000011}, \
{11001100010001110100001}, {10111000011100000111000}, \
{10100110101010100001100}, {}, {1111111111000000000000000}, \
{10111000000111111000000000}, {11010100000100000111110000}, \
{11100010000010000100001111}, {11000001100001100011001100}, \
{10100001010001010000111010}, {10010001001000011010100101}, \
{10001110000000101001010011}, {10001000011010010101010100}, \
{10000100101111000010000011}, {10000010110100101100101000}, \
{1100000011000101010010110}, {1010000110000110001100011}, \
{1001100010000011110001001}, {1001001001110000000111001}, \
{1000110100011001000110100}, {1000011001101010101000010}, \
{110000101001001001011001}, {101010010101000001100101}, \
{101001100010001110100010}, {100110001010110011001000}, \
{100101100100110100000101}, {11100001001100100100110}, \
{11010100100010010011010}, {10101010110001001001100}, \
{10011010011100110010000}, {}, {1111111111000000000000000}, \
{10111000000111111000000000}, {11000110000110000111100000}, \
{11000110000001100000011110}, {11000001100100010100011001}, \
{10110000010000010110000111}, {10110000001000001001111001}, \
{10001000011101000011010100}, {10001000011010100100101010}, \
{10000101100011001000100101}, {10000011100000111011000010}, \
{1101001000000001010101110}, {1100000110001100011001001}, \
{1010001010010010001110010}, {1010000101010001110010100}, \
{1001100001001001101000011}, {1000010011100110000100101}, \
{101100100000110001110100}, {100101001110100000010011}, \
{100011001011010100001100}, {100010110101001100010010}, \
{11011000001100110100001}, {11010100110000001000111}, \
{10101010100101101001000}, {10100101101010010101000}, \
{1110010010011010011000}, {}, {1111111111000000000000000}, \
{10111000000111111000000000}, {11000110000110000111100000}, \
{11000110000001100000011110}, {11000001100100010100011001}, \
{10110000010000010110000111}, {10110000001000001001111001}, \
{10001000011101000011010100}, {10001000011010100100101010}, \
{10000101100011001000100101}, {10000011100000111011000010}, \
{1101001000000001010101110}, {1100000110001100011001001}, \
{1010001010010001101010010}, {1010000101010010010110100}, \
{1001100001000101101000101}, {1000010011101010000100011}, \
{101100100001010001110010}, {100101001110100000010011}, \
{100011001011010100001100}, {100010110100101100010100}, \
{11011000001100110100001}, {11010100110000001000111}, \
{10101010100110001101000}, {10100101101001110001000}, \
{1110010010011010011000}, {}, {}, {"TOTAL NUMBER OF STRONGLY REGULAR \
GRAPHS =10"}, {}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
istr = Import["http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~es/SRGs/26-10-3-4", 
   "String"];
dim = ToExpression@
  First@StringCases[StringSplit[istr, {","}][[1]], NumberString]
(res = ToExpression@
       StringSplit[#, ""] &@
     StringCases[istr
      , Repeated["0" | "1", {dim}]
      ] // Partition[#, dim] &) // Map[MatrixForm]
```

Answer (score 3):

The zeros are not lost, the reason they disappear is, that you read the input as numbers and 00110 is simplified to 110.

To prevent this, read the input as a string:

```
inp =Import["http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~es/SRGs/5-2-0-1"]
```

Then extract the binary numbers as strings, convert then to characters and finally convert them do digits:

```
StringCases[inp, RegularExpression["(0|1){4}"]] /. 
 x_String :> ToExpression[Characters[x]]

{{0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}}
```

Comment: Nice! For importing files containing multiple matrices (`adjMatrix = Import["http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~es/SRGs/26-10-3-4"]`), is additional processing required? I am having issues using the same code. (This is not surprising.)

Comment: If the digit string is longer, say n bits, you have to adapt: RegularExpression["(0|1){n}"]] where n is the length.

Comment: I agree. I am still figuring out how to handle this. When I imported it, it seemed to have become some nested lists instead of strings (perhaps I missed something).

Comment: Do not import as "Data".. Specify no format or "String". If you have nested list, Flatten will un-nest them.